# Invalid access token when using Auth0

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, access-token, auth0

I am making use of the Auth0 service for my user authentication, but I have been having issues whereby the client id keeps returning an invalid user token.

The API accepts access tokens normally and verifies it on the back-end of the application built using NodeJS but at the front-end using ReactJS and Next.JS, I don't get access to a valid access token.

It returns something like this:

eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9kZXYtMnp0eGs5ODkudXMuYXV0aDAuY29tLyJ9..rMSEQS4g-2NcYvqU.zmMlNypJoKyO-wwLcxJgnsvcUHrcTH5c7jnNskyvxldZn56Tc_YX1T2vUQpWWNAWTyItAkUJxM58iy-kj29hY3Bz-Y1Q0Vccu8RdEip8Hc6p9f6-pR6bFKwVlLNkhj5oovFSDTv_-WPcYT40E5fTWRxaV4sNnE3ml16Bcu_CtFECmxAuJZWQ83dxWXlgudWXT7dhNMTGEyL2hIhWHlwO-dWkjIGI1wJmEa8v5pd0atawYsJlzukUcfc54alugCjIVEd1_QnGFWseKY05Ezl5VrBZJuEBnS8Qi6lMRreVPZkat64j_5jvEsvC5F5jMO9Qi2c.ezk5VSWPKZYdhBKkUhWP1Q

Also, I tried switching to ID token because that is valid but the JWT validator always returns 'Invalid_user'.

Attached below are some visual representations of the issue faced.

[image: auth0 command line issue 1]

[image: auth0 command line issue 2]

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the ID token with:

```
const jwtA = require("express-jwt");

var jwtCheck = jwtA({
    secret: process.env.AUTH0_SECRET,
    audience: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
    algorithms: ["RS256"]
});
```

or confirm in your frontend application that all settings are correct

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an opaque access token (see https://community.auth0.com/t/why-is-my-access-token-not-a-jwt-opaque-token/31028).

Auth0 uses these kinds of access tokens if you don't set a "audience" URL parameter in your /authorize API call (https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#database-ad-ldap-passive-). You can find the audience string in the Auth0 admin interface in the section "Applications -> APIs".

If you are using the [Auth0 Next.js SDK](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0), you can e.g. set the default audience via the "AUTH0_AUDIENCE" environment variable (see https://auth0.github.io/nextjs-auth0/modules/config.html#configuration-properties).